# Way to segment process output

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want some way to take the output of a process and split it up into batches. For example, in my case, I want to take the logs from a file and send me an email each time there is an entry.

So something like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/server.log | segment --delay=5 --command="sendmail me@example.com"
```

The above command would wait until there is 5 seconds of inactivity and then invoke the specified command with the output so far.

Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

With bash, you could do something like:

```bsh
segment () {
  while true
  do
    read -t "$TMOUT"  # read input with a timeout of $TMOUT seconds
    printf -v output "%s\n" "$output" "$REPLY"  # append to already read output

    if (( $? == 0 ))
    then
      # timeout not exceeded, so we can continue reading
      continue
    fi
    # some error occurred, run specified command with existing output
    printf "%s\n" "$output" | "$@"
    if (( $? > 128 ))
      # timeout exceeded, so we discard mailed output and continue
      output=""
    else
      # some other error, end loop
      return
    fi
  done
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
tail -f /var/log/server.log | TMOUT=5 segment sendmail me@example.com
```